# Cannot get Apache to restart

Tags: apache-2.2, windows

I have installed apache onto my computer and then went on to install php. I then edited the IniDir and LoadMoadule declarations in the httpd-conf file to indicate the location of the php installation. When I then tried to restart apache I was given the messege:

```
Windows could not start the Apache2.2 on Local Computer.
 For more information, review the system Event Log.
```

I have done a number of things to try to fix this but so far I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Did Apache run before you installed PHP? Try putting your config back to default and restart so as to troubleshoot the changes you have made. Also, have you checked the Event Log? There might be more information there, for example, the actual cause of the error ("port binding issue" for example).

Comment: I restarted Apache before I installed PHP and it worked. I checked the Event Log and it said there was an error with the changes I had made to the httpd-conf file. I went on to delete the changes and start afresh but Apache still fails to restart.

Comment: And what do the logs say now? Have you tried restarting your actual machine or checked if there are any processes running using taskmanager?

Comment: the report says: The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 495 of C:/Apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Apache/php5apache2_2.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: I have also checked the the port is not being used by any other application

Comment: Right, and the file is there, is it?

Comment: `"For more information, review the system Event Log."` - I assume that you've followed this advice, so can you post the relevant events?

Answer (score 1):

So... what did the event log say ?

Note that IniDir is not an apache directive, and should not occur in httpd.conf.

The LoadModule syntax is documented [**here**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule).

For you, it will take the form of:

```
LoadModule php5_module <module_location>/php5apache2_2.dll
```